# Leibnitz' rule in the context of random variables

Tags: calculus, probability

I am reading Papoulis and Pillai on probability and I think I am missing something very basic.  They give the following example for 2 random variables:

Let **z** = **x** + **y**.  Find $f_z(z)$ (the probability density function).

We start by observing

$$F_z(z) = P\{x + y \leq z\} = \int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{x=-\infty}^{z-y} f_{xy}(x,y)dxdy$$

They then bring up Leibnitz' rule: given $F_z(z) = \int_{a(z)}^{b(z)}f(x,z)dx$,

$$f_z(z) = \frac{dF_z(z)}{dz}=\frac{db(z)}{dz}f(b(z),z) - \frac{da(z)}{dz}f(a(z), z) + \int_{a(z)}^{b(z)}\frac{\partial f(x,z)}{\partial z}dx$$

Substituting back into our example

$$f_z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\int_{-\infty}^{z-y} f_{xy}(x,y)dx\right) dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(1\cdot f_{xy}(z-y,y) - 0 + \int_{-\infty}^{z-y}\frac{\partial f_{xy}(x,y)}{\partial z} \, dx \right)dy $$

So far I follow, as this is a direct application of Leibnitz' rule.  However, they next simplify and I don't understand the jump:

$$f_z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{xy}(z-y,y)dy $$

Specifically, I read the jump as keeping the term $\frac{db(z)}{dz}f(b(z),z)$ and removing the partial derivative with respect to $z$.  Am I wrong?  If so what is the right reading?  If not wrong, what happens to the partial derivative with respect to $z$?

Comment: $F_z(z) = \int_{a(z)}^{b(z)}f(x,y)\ dx$ is a function of $y$ and $z$; not only that of $z$ as the left hand side suggests. Something is fishy here.

Comment: @zoli typo corrected; apologies.

Comment: What is the relationship between $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ and $f(x,z)$? Can I say that $f(x,z)=f_{X,Z}(x,z)$, the common density of $X$ and $Z$?

Comment: In the expression $f(x,y)$, neither $x$ nor $y$ depend directly on $z$, that's why that term is eliminated.

Comment: @dafinguzman just to be clear, this is despite the fact that the integral is evaluated at a value of $z$?

Comment: @learner Yes, that is exactly what is taken into account in the first term. Leibnitz's rule basically accounts for three effects, one in each of its terms: the effect of increasing the integrating interval according to $b(z)$, the effect of decreasing the integrating interval according to $a(z)$, and the effect of changing the value of the function $f$ when it depends directly on $z$.

Comment: @dafinguzman thank you, that clears things up for me.  Would you mind writing this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression "$f(x,y)$" neither $x$ nor $y$ depend directly on $z$, that's why that term is eliminated.

This is despite the fact that the integration interval depends on the value of $z$: that is exactly what is taken into account in the first term.

Leibnitz's rule basically accounts for three effects related to small changes in the value of $z$, one in each of its terms:

1. The effect of increasing the integrating interval according to $b(z)$,
2. The effect of decreasing the integrating interval according to $a(z)$, and
3. The effect of changing the values of the integrand $f$ when it depends directly on $z$.